# setFilterQueryAdapter issues

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cursor setFilterQueryProvider issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678737/cursor-setfilterqueryprovider-issue)

I am trying to set up an edittext filter for my listview.

Currently I have the following code but keep getting errors on the 'setFilterQueryAdapter' on my cursorAdapter object.

I have this code in my 'OnCreate method' and as one of the errors is claiming the return type of 'void' is incorrect, I believe it should be out of onCreate but I'm not sure where.

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.
Here is the code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.appointmentview);

searchedAppView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

searchAppoints = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchAppointName); 
searchAppName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAppointName); 

    DBHandlerApp DBAppointments = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);

    DBHandlerApp searchApps = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);

    searchApps.open();


    Cursor cursor = searchApps.getAppointmentsData();
     searchApps.close();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);




    String [] from = new String [] {DBAppointments.KEY_NAMEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_TYPEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_TIMEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_DATEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_COMMENTAPP};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtAppointName, R.id.txtAppointType, R.id.txtAppointTime, R.id.txtAppointDate, R.id.txtAppointCom};






    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.setappointviews, cursor, from, to);
    searchedAppView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    searchedAppView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchAppoints.setOnClickListener(this);



    searchAppName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
     {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



                cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }


     });

    DBHandlerApp changedAppoint = new DBHandlerApp (this, null, null);

             ********** ERROR **********
     cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(FilterQueryProvider()
    {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            changedAppoint.open();
            return changedAppoint.getChanges(constraint.toString());

        }
    });


    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this issue out myself. It was due mainly to fact I had not imported the 'FilterQueryProvider'.